# How do I get the current taxonomy term from the plug-in context?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

When on a node, the following annotation will obtain the node from the context:

```
/**
 * @Condition(
 *   id = "node_type",
 *   label = @Translation("Node Bundle"),
 *   context = {
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"))
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

As shown here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/plugin-contexts

Is there an equivalent way to do this with taxonomy terms when on /taxonomy/term/%?

The code below certainly works but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner method like for nodes. Note that I'm also aware of the `Term::load($tid)` method but that still requires parsing the URL to obtain the tid and isn't portable (the code can be used only when run on a page).

```
  /**
   * Return current term.
   */
  public function getCurrentTerm() {
    $term = null;

    // Below we are using the general method to obtain the objects.
    // \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid) is the other

    // Get the unaliased path in the form /taxonomy/term/tid.
    $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

    preg_match('/\/taxonomy\/term\/\d+/', $current_path, $matches);

    // Return null if not in proper form.
    if (count($matches)) {
      // Find the parameters for this route.
      $params = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri("internal:" . $current_path)
        ->getRouteParameters();

      // Fetch the taxonomy object.
      $entity_type = key($params);
      $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage($entity_type)
        ->load($params[$entity_type]);
    }

    return $term;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can replace the code example with `$term = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term')`

Comment: The question is a little confusing. The first annotation you are showing is for a condition, which isn't used when viewing a node, but rather when defining a condition used for a block. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was just using that as an example. Your answer was perfect, thank you.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize the question was from you, kiamlaluno.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 10.05.2019:**

There is an unresolved issue about that on drupal.org: 
[Term route context](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2998826).

It uses the same solution as in my answer below.

**Original answer:**

You can create a custom context provider "Taxonomy term from URL".

service definition in `MYMODULE.services.yml`:

```
  MYMODULE.taxonomy_term_context:
    class: Drupal\MYMODULE\ContextProvider\TaxonomyTermContext
    arguments: ['@current_route_match']
    tags:
      - { name: 'context_provider' }
```

The /src/ContextProvider/TaxonomyTermContext.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\ContextProvider;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\Context;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextProviderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;

/**
 * Sets the current taxonomy term as a context on taxonomy term routes.
 */
class TaxonomyTermContext implements ContextProviderInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * The route match object.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface
   */
  protected $routeMatch;

  /**
   * Constructs a new object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The route match object.
   */
  public function __construct(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getRuntimeContexts(array $unqualified_context_ids) {
    $result = [];
    $context_definition = new ContextDefinition('entity:taxonomy_term', $this->t('Taxonomy term from URL'));
    $value = NULL;
    if (
      ($route_object = $this->routeMatch->getRouteObject())
      && ($route_contexts = $route_object->getOption('parameters'))
      && isset($route_contexts['taxonomy_term'])
    ) {
      if ($term = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('taxonomy_term')) {
        $value = $term;
      }
    }

    $cacheability = new CacheableMetadata();
    $cacheability->setCacheContexts(['route']);

    $context = new Context($context_definition, $value);
    $context->addCacheableDependency($cacheability);
    $result['taxonomy_term'] = $context;

    return $result;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getAvailableContexts() {
    $context = new Context(new ContextDefinition('entity:taxonomy_term', $this->t('Taxonomy term from URL')));
    return ['taxonomy_term' => $context];
  }

}
```

The ctools module provides already the condition plugin for entity bundles:`ctools/src/Plugin/Condition/EntityBundle.php`. You can use it together with the new service.

See also [config block visibility by vocabulary, but it not show block access fail(miss context)](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/issues/2712679#comment-12430421).

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be available in Drupal 9.1. See this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2998826)

```
/**
 * @Condition(
 *   id = "node_type",
 *   label = @Translation("Node Bundle"),
 *   context = {
 *     "taxonomy_term" = @ContextDefinition("entity:taxonomy_term", label = @Translation("Term"))
 *   }
 * )
 */
```